# Recursive LESS: "expected expression"

Tags: css, recursion, less

I am trying to implement a recursive loop in LESS 1.3.1. Never you mind what the mix-in is supposed to do (it has something to do with colors) in the end, but do mind why the recursive loop fails.

```
@iter: 4;

.loop(@index, @n) when (@index <= @n) { // throws "expected expression"?
    .foo@{index} { color: black; }
    .loop(@index + 1, @n);
}

.loop(@index, @n) when (@index > @n) {
    .terminated { color: white; }
}

.loop(1, @iter);
```

The mix-in `.loop` is supposed to do 4 iterations and then terminate, doing a `.terminated {}` or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your = and > the wrong way round

[Less Mixin Guards Documentation](http://lesscss.org/#-mixins)

"The full list of comparison operators usable in guards are: > >= = =< <. Additionally, the keyword true is the only truthy value, making these two mixins equivalent:"

```
.loop(@index, @n) when (@index <= @n)
```

should be

```
.loop(@index, @n) when (@index =< @n)
```

Comment: And I would have to email LESS and ask them why they chose to do it this way round... asking for trouble

Comment: Hahaha! I bow before you, because I would never have spotted that. I spent half an hour comparing with the example code...

Comment: :) I did double take when I saw the > >= = =< < because it's symmetrical (which I had never seen before in any other language). Anyway glad to help